# rewrite urls for product name

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite a rule for my products.

i want to use the id and name in the url separated by a dash like this:

> 123-name means product id = 123 and name = name

so in my php i can get the $_GET[id] and then query my database using this id like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Products Where productid = " . $_GET[id];
```

here's what i have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9+])\-([a-z]+)/?$ products.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

but when i put this as url, i get a 404

why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**First:** you have a syntax error. `[0-9+]` is a character class that can match (i) digits in the range `0` through `9`, or (ii) a `+` sign. To use the `+` as a quantifier (as intended), move the `+` after the `]`, like so: `([0-9]+)`.

**Second:** You are using `$2` in your item which is the product name. If you want to use the ID, you have to use `$1`.

Here's what you need to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ products.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

*I added in the product numbers, dash and underscore in case you need it someday.*

**Third:** 
You should be aware of [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), your script is not safe. You can fix this by using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use products.php?id=$1 because the first argument matched is the product id.