# Generate URL for specific category

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I need to modify URL based on product category. So in database example: name of category is `NIKE` and sub category is `AIR-MAX` so URL of this will be `site.com/en/products/nike/air-max/product.php?id=1`. So i need to generate `/nike/air-max/` if in database column `category` have `/nike/air-max/` else if in database column is another category example: `reebok` to display `/reebok/` url. I think this can be made with `echo function`.

```
class Main {
        public function get_all_posts(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE categoryProduct="Nike Air-Max" ORDER BY post_id DESC');
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function fetch_data($pid){
        global $pdo;

       $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post where post_id = ? order by post_date desc');
        $query->BindValue(1,$pid);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

I need to `echo "/nike/air-max/";` if `categoryProduct` have `Nike Air-Max` value or if `categoryProduct` have `reebook` to echo `/reebook/` so i can on index page echo that to `<a href="/en/product/<?php echo $post['URL']; ?>/product.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>">See product information</a>`

Comment: You'll need to use `.htaccess` to rewrite your URLs.

Comment: In .htaccess? How is there any tutorial or? Im to bad with .htaccess @Script47

Comment: I don't think the htaccess will be solution for this, PHP is solution. Because i need to create ```category/sub-category/``` from database not manual. @Script47

Comment: If category is ```nike/air-max``` which i retrieve from database column category then echo ```nike/air-max``` in url. @Script47

Comment: Can solution be ```switch``` function or something like that ?@Script47

Comment: @Script47 is correct, if you want customized url without actually creating the url page, you need `.htaccess` for rewriting.

Comment: [Here's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630457/rewrite-urls-for-product-name), and an explanation about [url rewriting](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Comment: ```my url need to be like this: http://website.com/en/products/nike/airmax/product.php?id=26``` how i can generate that into ```.htaccess```@CarlBinalla

Comment: There is **no such file** on your site like `/en/products/nike/air-max/product.php?id=1`. Hence,you will **have** to use a **mod_rewrite** rule (which php users mistakingly call .htaccess) to access your newly created urls. But that's a completely different story

Comment: and what should i write here ```<a href="en/products/????/????/product.php?id=1"></a>``` @YourCommonSense

Comment: Your categories. But a rewrite rule you have to put in your web-server configuration file, such as .htaccess. But again it's a different story. Refer to the question linked above.

Comment: I have min 11 categories and more then 30 sub-categories... @YourCommonSense

Answer (score -2):

First of all you have to divide the category from sub category in BD; so you have to create two separate tables: one for category and an other one containing the subcategory name and the category referement.

After do that you can simple do a retrive of all category and then foreach category do che retrive of subcategory and the display the name :

```
foreach ($result as $category) {
   foreach (retriveAllProdsFromCat($category) as $subCategory) {
       echo "<a href='site.com/en/products/$catgory/$subCategory/product.php?id=1'>$subCategory</a>";
   }
}
```

In this way you have to create a directory foreach category and each sub category; so idk if this is the best solution; but this is the right way to do a composite link

```
function retriveAllProdsFromCat($category) {
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM subcategory WHERE category=? ORDER BY post_id DESC');
    $query->bind_param('d', $category);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: you have to change something of course but the idea is this!

Comment: Idea is that but the function is not right, because i need to generate from database column ``` Nike - Air Max``` to ```nike/air-max/``` and with that code i can't do that, because in my form for retrieve that i use already ```<?php foreach($posts as $post){?>```

Comment: You are using MySQLi in your answer, and OP uses PDO